# python selenium - Unable to locate element in justdial site

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I already tried

1. Implicit and explicit wait
2. wait.until
3. Time module

Here I am trying to locate "**Load more reviews**" link on justdial. Here is the [link](https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154-B8G6_BZDET). Kindly check and help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154- 
B8G6_BZDET")



elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lmrehd"]')

elem.click()
```

Kindly give me some solution with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the span tag that contains Load more reviews as it's text.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get("https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154-B8G6_BZDET")

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load More Reviews..']")))
element.click()

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This website is dynamic , the id will change every time you reload the page ,

You can't use the id as a way to scrape it .

Try something else like text content